# Open activity from fragment instantly closed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I want to move to another activity from my fragment. I ve tried almost every solution which I found, but after I press button my app is instantly closed. I am new in java, and i guess i need some help.

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    Intent intent;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), HomeFragment.class);
        final Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from this line:

```
intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), HomeFragment.class);
```

That you're trying to launch a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`. In order to transition to another `Fragment`, replace your `Intent` with:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(...) //Or add, depends on your use case
            .commit();
    }
});
```